# Java Swing jtable cell editor doubles E numbers

Tags: swing, editor, jtable, double, cell

Hi I an issue with editors in a JTable.

I have a column which displays data as 26,687,489,800.00 ie: Double.

When the user clicks the cell to edit the data it is displayed as -2.66874908E10.

I want the data to be edited as it appears when it is displayed ie: 26,687,489,800.00 - without the E10 etc...

Any help would be appreciated.

Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should employ a [DecimalFormat](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) instance to format your value correctly when you setup your editor.

Comment: Hi I have created a text field and have formatted it using:
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat ("#,###,###,###,###,###,##0.######");

df.format (d);

I have assigned the JTextField as the Editor for my column BUT the I still get the same problem?

Any ideas? Am I missing something
Mike

Answer (score 2):

The component used as editor is completely different from the one used to display data (the renderer). This is why you have difference of format between the two of them.

I recommend you to read this [part of the Java tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#validtext), about adding your own cell editor. You should add a [Formatted text field](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html), to which you would [put the number format you need](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html#JFormattedTextField(java.text.Format).

Example:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat ("#,##0.######"); //you shouldn't need more "#" to the left
JFormattedTextField fmtTxtField = new JFormattedTextField(df);
TableCellEditor cellEditor = new DefaultCellEditor(fmtTxtField);

//This depends on how you manage your cell editors. This is for the whole table, not column specific
table.setCellEditor(cellEditor);
```

Comment: Hi I have created a text field and have formatted it using:
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat ("#,###,###,###,###,###,##0.######");

df.format (d);

I have assigned the JTextField as the Editor for my column BUT the I still get the same problem?

Any ideas? Am I missing something
Mike

Comment: @Michael - I think you should use a JFormattedTextField, for this task. I'm not sure what exactly you did with the regular JTextField and a DecimalFormat, but the normal use should be to create a JformattedTextField and give it the DecimalFormat as argument: http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html#JFormattedTextField(java.text.Format)

Answer (score 1):

If we consider that your column is of class Double you can do the following:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat ("#,##0.######");
JFormattedTextField fmtTxtField = new JFormattedTextField(df);
TableCellEditor cellEditor = new DefaultCellEditor(fmtTxtField);
table.setDefaultEditor(Double.class, new DefaultCellEditor(fmtTxtField));
```

but you need to overwrite the default delegate implementation of DefaultCellEditor. (At least in Java6)

```
//DEFAULT IMPLEMENTATION INSIDE THE CONSTRUCTOR
....
public DefaultCellEditor(final JTextField textField) {
    editorComponent = textField;
    this.clickCountToStart = 2;
    delegate = new EditorDelegate() {
        public void setValue(Object value) {
            textField.setText((value != null) ? value.toString() : "");
        }

        public Object getCellEditorValue() {
            return textField.getText();
        }
    };
textField.addActionListener(delegate);
}
....

//YOUR IMPLEMENTATION
public class DoublesCellEditor extends DefaultCellEditor {

    private JFormattedTextField textField;

    public DoublesCellEditor(JFormattedTextField jft) {
        super(jft);
        this.textField = jft;
        super.delegate = new EditorDelegate() {
            public void setValue(Object value) {
                textField.setValue(value != null ? ((Number) value).doubleValue() : value);
            }

            public Object getCellEditorValue() {
                Object value = textField.getValue();
                return value != null ? ((Number) value).doubleValue() : value;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

And instead use:

```
table.setDefaultEditor(Double.class, new DoublesCellEditor(fmtTxtField));
```